# Checking if an item in a String[] appears in a stream

Tags: java

I'm currently writing a parser for a language that I'm creating, which needs to check if the current part of the stream fits one of the items in the passed array. A short version of the code is:

```
public abstract class Parser {
    private StringReader reader; //This is a BufferedReader with rollback

    //A single string lookahead method
    public boolean lookahead(String toMatch, boolean rollback) throws ParseException {
        char c;
        //Mark the current position in the stream, so we can come back to it if needed
        MarkToken currentMark = reader.mark();

        //Iterate through the toMatch and check if each character matches
        for(int i = 0; i < toMatch.length(); ++i) {
            c = reader.nextChar();

            if(toMatch.charAt(i) != c) {
                break;
            }
        }

        //Get the current image
        String got = reader.currentImage(currentMark);

        //If we don't have a match, rollback if necessary and return false
        if(!got.equals(toMatch)) {
            if(rollback) {
                reader.rollBack();
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    //The String[] lookahead method
    public int lookahead(String[] toMatch, boolean rollback) throws ParseException {
        if(toMatch.length == 1) {
            //If there is only one element in toMatch, send it to a cheaper function
            if(lookahead(toMatch[0]))
                return 0;
            else return 1;
        } else {
            int maxLength = toMatch[0].length();
            //We use this variable to keep track of how many valid choices are left
            int choicesLeft = toMatch.length;
            int i, j;
            char current;
            //Mark the current position in the stream, so we can come back to it if needed
            MarkToken mark = s().mark();

            //Get the length of the longest string in toMatch
            for(i = 1; i < toMatch.length; ++i) {
                maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, toMatch[i].length());
            }

            //Go up to the length of the longest string
            for(i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i) {
                //Get the next character from the stream
                current = reader.nextChar();

                //If we've reached the end of the stream:
                if(current == -1 || current == '\uffff') {
                    //Get back a character in the stream
                    reader.rollbackChar();

                    //And check to see if we have a match
                    return ArrayUtils.indexOf(toMatch, reader.currentImage(mark));
                }

                //Go through each item in toMatch
                for(j = 0; j < toMatch.length; ++j) {
                    if(toMatch[j] != null) {
                        //Check to see if the character matches or not
                        if(toMatch[j].charAt(i) != current) {
                            //We null an item in toMatch if it doesn't apply any more
                            toMatch[j] = null;
                            --choicesLeft;
                        }
                    }
                }

                //If we only have one choice left, see if there is a match (will return -1 if not)
                if(choicesLeft == 1) {
                    return ArrayUtils.indexOf(toMatch, reader.currentImage(mark));
                }
            }

            //If there is no 
            if(rollback) {
                reader.rollBackTo(mark);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

This function would be called to check if the stream contained certain symbols (. .* $@ // " ' """ ''' etc.) and consume them greedily.

I would only be providing an array of maximum 10-15 items at once, so removing items from the array may not be the best optimisation.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this, certain methods or loops that I should be using?

Comment: It greatly depends on what's inefficient now.  If the reader is slow, you can compare with all of the elements in the array at once, one character at a time.  If you are doing thousands of checks and you want to speed them up, pull data out in chunks from the reader and check those chunks instead.  What is your current profile of performance, and where is the bottleneck for your required efficiency and scenarios?  If you can't answer this question, then you are not ready to ask the question of how to make this code better performance.

Comment: The code just works? Try it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I realised after I wrote this that if the stream was longer than any of the choices, the method would return -1. I suppose the only way you could get around that is if you got to that stage, you send back the longest match?

Comment: I'll go get the code working first then! :)

Comment: You ever get that code working?

Comment: Hi Fred, unfortunately most of my requirements have changed! I am using a different platform, a different lexer and my am rolling my own parser to fit my requirements. Thanks for asking though!